# R - data cleaning - return only numeric when not alpha

Tags: regex, r, data-cleaning

I am pretty new to programming, and suspect I need to use regular expressions to solve my problem.

**1. Problem**

I have data that needs to have the non-alphanumeric characters stripped - which I have solved. But I also need to return values where the elements are numeric-only.

**2. Example**

"NewdataColumn" is what I am trying to return.

```
MyDataColumn, NewdataColumn
12          , 12
2-3         , 23
Aa34        , NA
b-34        , NA
```

Any help would be appreciated.

***EDIT***
My partial solution was using the `stringr` package `gsub` function. e.g. `gsub("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "", MyDataColumn)`. Which got rid of the non-alphanumeric characters. The remaining problem is to return only numeric elements (if the element contains alpha, then return NA).

Comment: How are you determining that `Aa34` is `NA` but `2-3` is `23`? Could you clarify the rule?

Comment: Rule: IF the element contains alpha, then nothing should be returned i.e. `NA`.
ELSE, strip non-numeric.
I.E. I only want values returned when the element has no alpha characters and, if that is the case, I only want a clean number (not containing characters like  "-", "?","." etc.)

Comment: `IF the element contains alpha, then nothing should be returned` is not the same thing as `strip non-numeric`. I don't consider `-` "numeric" but it's also not a letter. It sounds like you want the former rule and not the latter.

Comment: I was expressing the rules as if they happened in order. In plainer language, "Get rid of cells with alpha, and clean up the remaining cells to leave numeric characters only".

Comment: `gsub` is in base, the corresponding function in `stringr` package is `str_replace` or `str_replace_all`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that regex is the way to go here.

First, initialize the column:

```
NewdataColumn <- rep(NA, length(MyDataColumn))
```

Then copy the entries that do not contain letters:

```
non_alpha <- grep("[[:alpha:]]", MyDataColumn, invert = TRUE)
NewdataColumn[non_alpha] <- MyDataColumn[non_alpha]
```

And finally strip out the non-numeric characters by substituting them with empty strings:

```
NewdataColumn <- gsub("[^[:alnum:]]", "", NewdataColumn)
```

Reguar expressions are a very useful tool. I often use [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info) as a reference, and they also have a few tutorials that might help you get started. Fortunately the regex in this example is pretty straightforward, so it might be a good early goal for comprehension.

That said, regular expressions are enormously complicated, if only because there are several different implementations and they all differ slightly. Perl and Python, for instance, both offer greatly extended engines, but at the end of the day every extension more syntax to remember -- and more regular expressions you *can't* write because you'll accidentally match something you don't mean to match. It can sometimes be hard to remember what is considered "extended" in different contexts, and extensions aren't always portable.

That said, I've been using regular expressions constantly for about a year, and I'm only now just starting to be able to make use of features beyond simple pattern matching. Start slow with some basic examples. As you get more comfortable, you'll start seeing more applications for them, and by that time you'll be ready to learn more. Python regex is an especially good learning tool because you can actually include comments and non-parsed whitespace if you enable the "verbose" option.

Comment: This was very helpful. The only other difficulty I ran into was R's treatment of the column as a factor rather than a character. Once I used `as.character`, your solution worked. Thanks.